# ROracle package load fails on windows 7 after install

Tags: r, roracle

I looked everywhere and followed the exact instructions provided, but run into this error when I load the library on my Windows 7 machine:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’
```

Here is my R version:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree
```

I downloaded the ROracle binary for Windows from this page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/downloads/index.html

I used the ROracle 1.2-1 version.

My OCI_LIB64 and PATH environmental variables are as follows:

```
OCL_LIB64=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
PATH:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
```

Anything else I am missing? How can I get this to work?

I have administrator rights to all the folders, including the library paths.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle Instant Client to fix this error, as indicated at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E67822_01/OREAD/apx_typicalinstall.htm#OREAD274.

Your OCL_LIB64 and PATH variable point to some kind of a \bin directory, when they should point to the Instant Client unzip directory (which has no \bin inside in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Oracle Client 32 and 64 bits witk SDk folder directory to then Windows System enviromental variables path. Also need to install rjava package (install java 64 bits) and set JAVA_HOME in R sys.setenv().

```
install.packages("rJava")       #Install Java 64 bits
library(rJava)                  #Not Errors

Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB64"="C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")
Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB32" = "C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")
Sys.setenv("ORACLE_HOME" = "C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241')

install.packages(paste0(path,"/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")
library(ROracle)
```

The last message in the install process should be DONE!

In the Windows System enviromental path:

```
C:\instantclient_12_2_64bits;
C:\instantclient_12_2_64bits\sdk;
C:\instantclient_12_2_32bits;
C:\instantclient_12_2_32bits\sdk;
```

hope this works!

Comment: Since ROracle doesn't use any Java or JDBC interface, there shouldn't be a need to install a JRE

Comment: Maybe, but I was trying to install the ROracle package for a week and this setup finally worked.